# Android Twitter login via native application

Tags: android, twitter, authentication, oauth

I would like to create Twitter authentication, the same as facebook when we have installed native Twitter application.

It should work that we click "Login via Twitter", and it checks if we have Twitter application installed, and take user id and email to make possible authentication with no need to type text.

Comment: I really want Twitter to implement this like Facebook and Google. How hard can it be?